# How to Download C code to De1-SoC and get it running

Tags: arm

I have a [DE1-SoC board](http://www.terasic.com.tw/cgi-bin/page/archive.pl?Language=English&No=836) and would like to play with it.

My wish is to write a simple program in C, compile, then upload the binary to the board. However, I am not sure where to start from.

**Do I understand correctly, that there are two ways of executing code on DE1-SoC:**

- 1) Upload synthesized HDL code for FPGA to execute
- 2) Use HPS processor to execute ARM instructions?

I have successfully realised the first case. Now I want to explore the second case.

**How to upload compiled C code for HPS processor to run**?

Comment: C code does not run natively. You compile it to a binary. Which means that you probably want a compiler on the SoC, or a cross compiler set to produce the right code (arm).

Comment: I imagine compiling c on PC and uploading the binary to SoC is easier than compiling c on the SoC itself? Now suppose I have the compiled binary code. My main question is HOW to upload it so that the SoC would start executing the code?

Comment: Setting up cross compilation is almost certainly harder. But it also tends to be much faster.  As for the rest, someone else will have to answer that. I have no experience with a DE1.